# javascript encodeURIComponent and escape?

Tags: javascript, escaping, encodeuricomponent

I use JS to sent encodeURIComponent string to a PHP file write and has been working fine for years; until recently I met with a strange effect that the text need to be further encoded with escape in order to get it to work! The sympton start to show only when I use an open source wysiwyg editor !

What could be the offending characters in URI that need escape to fix it? I used to think URI only reserve ? & = for its syntax to work.

Comment: Please provide the specific strings in question, and what happens when you apply `encodeURIComponent` to them, and what the "strange effect" is that makes you think the text needs to be further encoded. By the way, encoding URIs involves many, many characters than just `?` and `#`, although it is not at all clear that that is related to your problem.

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` encodes all but: `A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )`, and `escape` encodes special characters except: `@*_+-./`

Answer (score 0):

The situation you describe could possibly be explained--although there's no way of knowing without you telling us what the string is, and how it's being used--by a URL which involves two levels of nested URL-like values.

Consider a URL taking a query parameter which is another URL:

```
http://me.com?url=http://you.com?qp=1
```

That URL is subject to misinterpretation, so we would normally URL-encode the `you.com` URL, giving us:

```
http://me.com?url=http%3A%2F%2Fyou.com%3Fqp%3D1
```

Whoever is working with this URL can now extract the query parameter named `url` with the value `http%3A%2F%2Fyou.com%3Fqp%3D1`, decode it (often a framework or library will decode it for you), and then use it to jump to or call that URL.

Consider, however, the case where the `you.com` URL itself has a query parameter, not `?qp=1` as given in the first example, but rather something that itself needs to be URL-encoded. To keep things simple, we'll just use "cat?pictures". We'd need to encode that, making the query parameter

In other words, the URL in question is going to be

```
?qp=cat%3Fpictures
```

If we just use that as is, then our entire URL becomes

```
http://me.com?url=http%3A%2F%2Fyou.com%3Fqp=cat%3Fpictures
```

Unfortunately, if we now decode that in a naive way, we get

```
http://me.com?url=http://you.com?qp=cat?pictures
```

In other words, the nested URL has been decoded as well, meaning that it will think the URL has two query paramters, namely `url` **and** `qp`. To successfully deal with this problem, we need to encode the second query parameter a second time, yielding

```
http://me.com?url=http%3A%2F%2Fyou.com%3Fqp%3Dcat%253Fpictures
```

Please note, however, that if you use your language or environment's built-in tools and libraries for handling query parameters, most of this will happen automatically and prevent you from having to worry about it.

> The symptom start to show only when I use an open source wysiwyg editor

An editor merely places characters in a file. It's very hard to imagine that an editor is causing the problem you refer to, unless perhaps one editor is configured to use smart quotes, for example, which would pretty much break everything that involved quotes.

Comment: Yes, I thought the same logic as you explained. It can not be caused by the editor and in the past 
I do not need the txt=escape(txt) line. I have closely look at the difference between encodeURICoponent 
and escape, and the only character that I can think maybe the offdender is the  ~ symbol which I used to 
signal the end of the file. But should it ?

Comment: <blockquote>
function saveText() {
 var txt= "";
 for (i=0; i<pageCnt; i++) { 
  if ( pages[i] === "") { continue;}
  txt = txt + pages[i] + "\n"; 
  }
 
 txt = encodeURIComponent(txt);
 txt = escape(txt);   // ??? why this is needed?
 var prog = "/acwphp/API_Write_TextFile.php?fullname=" + encodeURIComponent(fname) +"&text=" + txt;
 //alert(prog);
 runExternalProg(prog, function(rtn) {
  alert(rtn);
 });
} 
</blockquote>

Comment: Do not put this code in a comment. Please add it to your question. In general, do not paste together URLs yourself. Use a library like [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), or the one provided by your framework.